# Ipad websiteData under settings

Tags: html, ipad

WHen does the website data under Safari->Settings->Advance->WebSite Data gets populated.
Actually i am facing a problem because of that. And is there any way(progrmatically) we can avoid getting it populated.

I am using Ipad 4. and i have created a mobile web site with HTML5 App cache feature 
Thanks.

With Best Regards,
Sajesh Nambiar

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue...HTML5 App manifest was causing the problem....Safari browser caches the page when the network is slow was causing the issue.